# Run Compute Shader on CPU's SIMD

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

Using the opencl library and intel or amd opencl cpu drivers, it is possible to run the code on the simd of cpu and gpu and it gives very good performance. Is there any way to run the Compute Shader (GL or DX) on the cpu's simd?

Comment: there's no such thing as "simd of cpu". Maybe you mean "floating point co-processor of cpu", which happens to implement SIMD instructions.

Comment: @MarcB Of course, cpus also have SIMDs but they are not as wide as cpus. SSE instructions are the instructions which are going to be run on the cpu's SIMD.

Comment: @mmostajab I don't think you know what [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) means. It stands for "Single Instruction, Multiple Data". It's a class of assembly instructions, not a physical thing. In any case, I doubt there's a way to specify where compute shaders are ran.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two, so what is the difference between running a code on different threads on the cpu and running it with OpenCL ? Is it only based on the assembly of the instructions?

Comment: @mmostajab The OpenCL compiler can use the SIMD instructions on the CPU, though so can a regular program if it's coded to use them. But the OpenCL script can be ran on either the CPU or GPU interchangeably without any major changes.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo OK! So, I should ask is it possible to run the compute shader on the cpu but using the simd instructions?